# Magento 2 - Get location of view model of knockoutjs .html template

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, html, view

For example, how can I find out where the model / view model for this template is located at?

[vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html)

Answer (score 2):

To detect the Knockout JS component's location belongs to a Knockout HTML template, you will need to use the search term combination of the module component name and the relative path of the template file without `html` extension counting from the first character after the **web/template/** string, like this:
**Vendor_Module/relative/path/of/the/template/file/without/html/extension**

You can get the module component name in `<module directory>/registration.php`.

There are 2 places where Knockout JS templates can be declared:

- in the UI component file
- in the Knockout JS component

For example, the HTML template is **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html**:

- the module component name of **vendor/magento/module-checkout** is **Magento_Checkout**
- the relative path of the HTML template without the html extension is **minicart/item/default**

Here we have search term is: **Magento_Checkout/minicart/item/default**

You will get the result in the file vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart-item-renderer</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/item/default</item>
</item>
```

You can see there is a `component` config node same level as the `config` node which declares the template, this is the Knockout JS component you are searching for: **Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart-item-renderer** (vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart-item-renderer.js).

In other cases, you can find the code declaring the Knockout HTML template in the Knockout JS component like the following. That is the Knockout JS component you are searching for.

```
defaults: {
    template: 'Magento_Checkout/progress-bar'
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found the Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart-item-renderer component, but it does not contain the definitions for the template. For example the template uses ` <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->` and **product_has_url** is not defined in that component. So how does the template know where it is defined?

Comment: Hey @Black, I currently don't have time to provide a details answer to this additional question. However, I can give you an insight in case you are working on a task and need to find some information asap.

Comment: **product_has_url** does not declare directly in the Knockout JS component file which belongs to the HTML template, but it is declared in a related JS Knockout component via private content (`cartData = customerData.get('cart');` which is pulled the data from the backend. Finally, in the backend, the **product_has_url** variable declared in **doGetItemData** in vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

Comment: "But it is declared in a related JS Knockout component via private content"

Where can I find that component? How is it linked to the template?

Comment: I’ll need to check. Maybe I can find the time to do this next week. :)

Comment: Hey @Black I have a great and detailed answer to your additional question. Do you think we should add a separate question from the original question? The original question doesn't seem to be related to the additional question, but I think it's valuable and worth exploring. The choice is yours, and either way, I'm happy with your choice.

Comment: You can edit your answer and add your second answer below or create a new answer. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

ViewModels are defined in layout xml files.

So you should search all layout xml files for the usage of the template file.
then take a look at the search results and review the definition of the block and check the argument-nodes that are provided.

Comment: I searched it, but there is only a component defined which has two methods which are not even used in that template.

Comment: @Philipp Sander is talking about the wrong topic, which is "View Models" PHP classes, not "view model" in Knockout JS!!